# Shiny send output$ to Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, output

I would like to work with R-Data via Shiny in my Frontend (JavaScript).

Therefore, I added an eventReactive, manipulating data.
The generated selectedElement should then be pushed to the frontend.
I was trying this as below:

**R-Code**

```
#server.R
selectedElement<- eventReactive(input$selectID,{
    data %>% filter(ElementID == "XYZ", row_number() == 1)
  })


observeEvent(input$selectID,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                              selectedElement
})
```

**JavaScript - Code**

```
//.js
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
        console.error(event.name);
})
```

The issue is, that the output$ is not noticed by JavaScript. That's why I think it is not send and would like to know what went wrong.

Thanks a lot!